# css selectors when the elements are not neighbors

Tags: html, css

I have next code:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class='error'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to if that `input:focus` then `div.error` must be display none

Comment: Can you please reword your question? you mean if input has focus you want div.error to display none?

Comment: Yes. sorry for the bad wording)

Comment: If you can't rewrite HTML or use JS it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input id="myinput" />
  </div>
  <div class='error'>
  </div>
</div>

You can use jquery
$( "#myinput" ).focus(function() {
  $( ".error" ).hide();
});
```

Comment: We need no js. only css )

Comment: i understand ,sorry .

Answer (score -1):

This could work:

```
     input:focus .error{display: none;}
```